# letsencrypt azure webjob pending restart

Tags: azure, lets-encrypt, webjob

I setup letsencrypt on a web app on azure at the start of the year, and all was running fine, until today when we found the webjob hadn't auto-renewed the certificate.

any ideas why it conked out?

when trying to check the logs, it states I need to add a connection string with the value with the format:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY
```

where can I find the values for NAME and KEY?

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be the `NAME` & `KEY` of your Azure Storgae Account.

You can find the values on Azure classic portal or new portal, please see below.

Fig 1. On Azure classic portal
[image]

Fig 1. On Azure new portal
[image]